# Remove starting and ending double quotes

Tags: java

my input is `"[/^^/]"`.

I want the output like `[/^^/]` in java.

I have already tried

```
a.replace("\"", "")
```

Please help

Comment: What happened with what you tried?

Comment: Use replaceAll() to replace all the occurance of double quotes.

Comment: Note that `String` is immutable.

Answer (score 2):

```
String a = "\"[/^^/]\"";
a = a.replace("\"", "");
System.out.println(a);
```

Works for me. **Don't forget that `String` is immutable in Java**, so you have to store the result of your replace in your variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String s= "\"[/^^/]\"";
s = s.substring(1,s.length()-1));
System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
a= a.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Another one:

```
a = a.replaceAll("^\"(.*)\"$","$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this , this code **removes only first and last** occurrence of double quotes and **not all occurrences** of double quotes.

```
String input_string = "\"He said\"I am not intrested\"\"";

            String after_first_replace = input_string.replaceFirst("\"", "");

            String final_input = after_first_replace.substring(0, after_first_replace.lastIndexOf("\""));
            System.out.println(final_input);
```